# data member with the class name

Tags: c++, class, visual-c++, member, classname

The standard says, 
"A member of a class T cannot use T as its name if the member is a static data member, a member function, a member type, a member template, an enumerator of an unscoped enumeration, a member of a member anonymous union. However, a non-static data member may use the name T as long as there are no user-declared constructors."

However if I create this class, it gives an compile error.

```
class G
{
    int G;
};
```

I am using VS2013. Is it not allowed in Microsoft or ?

Comment: What is the compile error ? This is working with Clang and GCC.

Comment: microsoft compilers are (in)famous for their failure to conform to any kind of standard.

Comment: error: C2380: type(s) preceding 'G' (constructor with return type, or illegal redefinition of current class-name?)
So, they do not allow it :(

Comment: I highly recommend naming class and members differently.  I've never had this issue because I keep the names different.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews sure I never used this in practice either.

Answer (score 3):

If VC++ doesn't allow this, it's a bug.

However, this language "feature" is for the purpose of C compatibility, and Microsoft has decided not to emphasize C. For example, C99 features are unavailable as a rule until adopted by C++. You should never purposely declare such a member in C++.

(It's allowed in C simply by default: there are no restrictions on the naming of members, and all members are nonstatic data members.)